# Não carrega tag video [ HTML ]

Tags: javascript, html, css, react

não consigo carregar vídeo na minha aplicação React. Estou usando o chrome porém também testei no Safari. Só me gera uma tela branca. A tag é reconhecida pois quando eu uso controls ele habilita. Mas a tela branca continua lá sem ao menos substituir pelo poster setado.

Já olhei todos os tutoriais, outros posts, testei vídeos diferentes, webM, mp4, tudo e não funciona. O código parece estar totalmente correto. Alguém aí já passou por isso?

Segue código:

```
import React from 'react';

//import { VideoContainer } from './style';

const Main = () => {
    return (
        <video autoplay muted loop //controls="controls"
         style={{ 
            //objectFit: "cover",
            width: "100vw",
            height: "100vh",
            position: "fixed",
            top: "0",
            left: "0",
            zIndex: 10,
            border: "10px solid green" 
         }}
        >
            <source src="backgroundIII.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            Vídeo não suportado
        </video>
    );
};

export default Main;
```

Answer (score -2):

O `source` não esta localizando o backgroundIII.mp4

Coloca o vídeo na pasta [public](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/).

Ai modifica o source:

```
<source src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/backgroundIII.mp4'} type="video/mp4" />
```